# Stop agent job after executing for a certain number of hours

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-agent

I have a scheduled job which runs nightly. I want it to stop itself at 07:00AM in the morning whether or not it is completed.
I have seen some duplicates in the site but they don't exactly address the problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally I would create another job and schedule it to run each morning at 7am.

A job step within that job could execute something like

```
USE msdb ;
GO

EXEC dbo.sp_stop_job
    N'<Your job name>' ;
```